# If $A$ is equal to $\log(B)$, is $A$ proportional to $B$?

Tags: logarithms

Simple question, but I'm doubting myself here.

If $A = \log(B)$, is $A \propto B$?

I understand proportionality as: *If $A$ is proportional to $B$, $A$ increases as $B$ increases*.

Is this true?

Comment: Most people would demand proportionality should be linear:  $A=kB$ for some non-zero constant $k$.  In this case, no.

Comment: Your understanding of proportionality is too broad:)

Comment: No, but you can say something more general, like "$A$ and $B$ are positively associated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say $A$ is a monotonous increasing function of $B$, i.e. if $A$ increases then so does $B$. You cannot say they are proportional since, according to the definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)), this means there is a constant ratio between the two quantities, i.e $A=kB$. This does not hold here.